# Why does Skype on Ubuntu need the mysql-common package?

Tags: ubuntu, skype, dependencies

When installing Skype on Ubuntu 15.04 a plethora of other packages is installed, too. Among these is mysql-common which piqued my interest. Can somebody explain what Skype might need that package for?

Comment: probably to store information like chat history.

Comment: Because Skype uses mysql for one of its features and that is the package that is required.

Comment: It is not installing a mysql server. The package only contains common stuff needed by the client: 
"This package includes files needed by all versions of the client library,
 e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf."

Comment: @ChristophGrimmer-Dietrich - Skype is closed source.  So what feature of Skype requires that package, we can't know for sure, just that it is required for Skype to function.  You can have a sql database without using a mysql server

Answer (score 1):

Skype is closed-source and the explanation for dependencies is not documented.

The following are my best ***guesses*** for requiring mysql-common.

**Guess 1**: The Skype servers store user data in a MySQL server.  The Skype client uses the mysql-common libraries to connect to a remote MySQL server for authentication, user data, and possibly communication.

**Guess 2**: The mysql-common library includes functions useful for reading the local SQLite data files.

Skype (4.3.0.37) stores some of its local data in a SQLite database.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ file $HOME/.Skype/shared_dynco/dc.db
/home/ubuntu/.Skype/shared_dynco/dc.db: SQLite 3.x database
```

**Guess 3**: The dependency itself is not actually required for execution and was inadvertently added.

Comment: This may be accurate, but doesn't explain the need for mysql-common.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton - Why? Wouldn't that library be required to perform queries on the sqlite database?

Comment: MySQL and SQLite are two different products. There's no need for, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf to use SQLite.

Comment: Case of  feature and permission creep -- gotta love closed source...  best advise especially for it is jail  / sandbox and lock out your firewall ...netstat is  nice for showing the persistent  ports for *.sql data

Comment: I'd go with guess 3 :-/